# Why doesn't R.raw.'songname' not work on android devices?

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, archos

I have some media (Audio tracks) on an app, with file path 'R.raw.test'.

I use some code to get it into a mediaplayer:

```
MediaPlayer.create(Textbox.this, R.raw.fly);
```

And it works PERFECTLY on the Android Emulator (plays track on click of button).

Why, when I put it on my Archos (5 IT) it doesn't work at all?

As soon as the button is clicked, it crashes. Do you have to do something to file paths or what?

Comment: I suppose you mean `R.raw.fly` and not `R.raw.test` (or vice versa)?

Comment: Yeah, just did that for example, both are 'R.raw.fly'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4f93f48045ec4ce3/f1f14bef38e1e02b?lnk=gst&q=MediaPlayer.create#f1f14bef38e1e02b) thread.
`MediaPlayer.create(Textbox.this, R.raw.fly);` should work on your Archos.

Comment: Yeah I know it should, but for some reason it just crashes... =/